# Duda inicios con Java

Tags: java

[image]

Estoy empezando con el manejo de Java, y no sé que hago mal para que no me muestre el nombre bien (también me ha pasado con otros ejercicios).

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 2):

En los sitios del StackExchange relacionados con la programación es preferible que copies el código, no que incluyas una captura de pantalla. De forma que la gente que intente ayudarte pueda copiarlo fácilmente en su propio ordenador para probarlo y manipularlo.

Así

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        persona persona1 = new persona("Juan");
        System.out.println(persona1);

        persona persona2 = new persona("Karla");
        System.out.println(persona2);
    }

    private static class persona {
        public persona(String juan) {
        
        }
    }
}
```

Cuando ejecutas esta línea de código

```
 System.out.println(persona1);
```

La máquina virtual de Java lo que hace internamente es ejecutar esto

```
 System.out.println(persona1.toString());
```

Es decir invoca el método `toString` de la clase persona. Método que no has definido explícitamente, con lo cual el que se ejecuta es el método de la clase `Object` de la que heredan todos las clases de java.

Este método lo que hace es escribir el nombre de la clase, seguido de @ y una dirección de memoria, por eso estás obteniendo
`com.company.Main$persona@5f184fc6`

Para que funcione como esperas tienes que **sobreescribir el método toString** en la clase persona. Aprovecho para señalarte que los nombres de clase en Java se recomienda por convención que empiecen por mayúscula: Persona. Para tus primeros ejemplos además te recomiendo que no uses clases internas, dedica un fichero separado para cada clase. La clase Persona debería estar definida en su propio fichero Persona.java

```
package com.company;

public class Persona {

       private String nombre;

       public Persona(String nombre) {
           this.nombre = nombre;
       }

       public String getNombre() {
           return nombre;
       }

       public void setNombre(String nombre) {
           this.nombre = nombre;
       }

       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return nombre;
       }

}
```

Si ejecutas esto

```
package com.company;

public class MainTwo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Persona persona1 = new Persona("Juan");
    System.out.println(persona1);

    Persona persona2 = new Persona("Karla");
    System.out.println(persona2);
}
}
```

Obtendrás el resultado esperado

```
Juan
Karla
```

[Aquí tienes un enlace en español](https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/javaya/detalleconcepto.php?punto=94&codigo=174&inicio=80) con un ejemplo muy parecido al que tú estás intentando desarrollar, donde se abunda en los elementos que te he expuesto.