# Problema con métodos de pilas en Java

Tags: java, array, pilas

Estoy teniendo un problema con los métodos de pilas para un arreglo de objetos. El programa genera 50 personas al azar con sus IDs y edades, luego las divide según su edad en arreglos diferentes y después a los arreglos los guarda en pilas.

El problema lo estoy teniendo con el método display, si uso el ciclo con la linea `System.out.println(persona[i]+" ");` logro obtener solamente la dirección de memoria de la persona, y si uso la linea `System.out.println(persona[i].Id+" "+persona[i].edad);` entonces lo único que devuelve son valores nulos. Agradecería si me pueden ayudar con esto.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        //create array of employee object  
        Persona[] personas = new Persona[50] ;
        Persona[] menores = new Persona[50];
        Persona[] adultos = new Persona[50];
        Persona[] ancianos = new Persona[50];
        Pila pMenores = new Pila (50);
        Pila pAdultos = new Pila (50);
        Pila pAncianos = new Pila (50);

         for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
         {
             personas[i] = new Persona (generadorId(100000000, 999999999), generadorEdad(0,100));
         }
         
         int contMenores = 0;    
         int contAdultos = 0;
         int contAncianos = 0;

         for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
         {
            if(personas[i].edad <= 18)
            {
               menores[contMenores] = personas[i];
               contMenores++;
            }
            else if(personas[i].edad > 18 && personas[i].edad <= 69)
            {
               adultos[contAdultos] = personas[i];
               contAdultos++;
            }
            else if(personas[i].edad >=70)
            {
               ancianos[contAncianos] = personas[i];
               contAncianos++;
            }
         }
         
         
         for (int i = 0; i < menores.length; i++) {
             pMenores.push(menores[i]);
        }
         
    }
    

    static class Persona{
      int Id;
      int edad;

      Persona(int pId, int e){
         Id = pId;
         edad = e;
      }
      
      public void showData(){
        System.out.print("Identificacion: "+Id + "  " + " Edad: "+edad);
        System.out.println();
    }
    }
    
    static class Pila{
        private Persona[] persona;
        private int top;
        private int tamActual;
        
        Pila(int tam){
            persona = new Persona[tam];
            tamActual = 0;
            top = -1;
        }
        
        public void push(Persona x ){
            if (tamActual == persona.length){
                System.out.println("Capacidad llena");
                System.exit(1);
            }else
            {
                top++;
                persona[top] = x;
                tamActual++;
            }
        }
        
        public Persona pop(){
            if(tamActual==0){
                System.out.println("Ya esta vacio");
                return null;
            }else
            {
                Persona x = persona[top];
                persona[top] = null;
                top--;
                tamActual--;
                return x;
            }
        }
        
        void display()
        {
            for(int i = top; i >=  0; i--)
            {
                System.out.println(persona[i]+" ");
            }
            
        }
    }
    public static int generadorId(int min, int max){
    double id;
        id = ((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min); //Genera una ID aleatoria
    
    return (int) id; //Devuelve la ID
    } 
    
    public static int generadorEdad(int min, int max){
    double edad;
        edad = ((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min); //Genera una edad aleatoria
    
    return (int) edad; //Devuelve la edad
    } 
    
}
```

Comment: Sobre lo de "obtengo únicamente la posición de memoria", puedes leer [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/453459/duda-inicios-con-java/453472#453472)

Comment: "si uso la linea `System.out.println(persona[i].Id+" "+persona[i].edad);` entonces lo único que devuelve son valores nulos." `Id` y `edad` son valores `int`, NO PUEDEN SER NULOS. Explica mejor qué es lo que obtienes. ¿Quizás quieres decir que ves ceros?

Comment: Lo que obtengo es la excepción NullPointerException, sin que imprima ningún valor

Comment: Y en los arreglos se guarda bien la informacion

Comment: Creo que mi respuesta es correcta, espera 50 personas, pero es aleatorio en un rango de 0 a 100, es probable que no se llene el arreglo con estas 50, por lo que quedan espacios en nulo. y el trata de a fuerza impremir el id y la edad en un valor nulo. Me compila bien con lo que hice en mi respuesta

Comment: Japv, sí, las 50 personas son generadas correctamente así como la posterior clasificación de acuerdo a las edades, hasta ese punto funciona bien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trata de comprobar si `if(persona[i] != null)` y ahí imprimir `System.out.println(persona[i].Id+" "+persona[i].edad);` en el método display, de esta manera no salta error, estas reservando 50 espacios para el arreglo pero no se llegan a generar 50 personas menores de edad, ya que el rango va de 0 a 100, creo que este es el problema.

Cuando generas el id y la edad estas declarando que se generen las edades de 0 a 100, si tu cambias `(0,100)` por `(0,18)` veras que todas las personas de pMenores se imprimen correctamente.

`pMenores.display()` Tratara de imprimir las personas que hay en este arreglo. osea solo los que se hallan generado con edad menor o igual a 18, pero recordá que esto es aleatorio, no todos son menores, por lo que hay valores que quedaron nulos

Al igual que si hubieras hecho `pAdultos` o `pAncianos`, debes comprobar si se diferencia de nulo.

Podrás seguir usando el rango de edad de 0 a 100, pero en el método `display` deber comprobar eso, ya que no todos son menores, ni todos adultos ni ancianos.

Creo que este es el problema que tenias, ya que al ejecutar tu código saltaba el `NullPointerException` y al hacer esto que te dije, todo funciona correctamente.

Comment: Era la comprobación de que personas [i] no estuviera vacío, muchas gracias por la ayuda